# RefinementList not working on my data

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, searchkit

I'm currently using searchkit component for reactjs UI project. We have our own data, but RefinementList component is not working on it.

```
<RefinementListFilter field="type.raw" id="type" operator="OR />
```

Is there any setup needed for elasticsearch data about the .raw?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Elastic are you using? The default name for keyword fields changed from Elastic v2.x to 5.x. It's now `.keyword`.

So in your code, try changing "type.raw" to "type.keyword", if you're not using an index template.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks !